# Is Athanasius' translation of Isaiah 9:6 supportable?

Tags: isaiah, word-choice

[Athanasius of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasius_of_Alexandria) translates :

> ... the everlasting father ... [Isaiah 9:6 KJV]

as :

> ... Father of the coming age ... ['On Luke 10:22' from Select Works and Letters (1) ].

I notice that Robert Young translates this as :

> ... Father of eternity ... [YLT].

Does the Hebrew (Masoretic Text) support Athanasius' rendering ?

---

(1) Page 266 of [Select Works and Letters](https://d2y1pz2y630308.cloudfront.net/15471/documents/2016/10/St.%20Athanasius-Select%20Works%20and%20Letters.pdf)

Comment: I answered on the same or duplicate que of YLT mistranslation, that it must be a trinitarian or pseudo-trinity bias that sees a conflict in identifying Messiah as Eternal Father, so they preferred to change the plain word. Abi-ad means eternal father. Athanasius having a subordinate hyper trinity of a begotten son would have the same bias in mistranslation https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47489/why-is-jesus-called-the-father-of-eternity-at-isaiah-96-in-the-ylt also see https://ladderofjacob.com/2022/05/02/shalom/

Comment: He was translating from LXX which was likely  ABP version πατήρ του μέλλοντος αιώνος Father of coming (messianic) age. But YLT has no excuse as he translated from Hebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operative Hebrew word in Isa 9:6 is אֲבִיעַ֖ד ('abi'ad) - a compound word  of father + perpetuity/eternity (עַד BDB), eg, Gen 15:18, Isa 57:15, Ps 111:3, 10, 112:3, 112:9, 132:14, 19:10, etc..  As with such Hebrew compound words, one might validly translate this as:

- everlasting father (eg, NIV, BSB, ESV, etc)
- father of eternity (eg, YLT)
- eternal father (eg, NASB, CSB, CEV, etc)

However, I struggle to see a valid justification for "father of the coming age"; this appears to have been motivated by Ananasius' theology or similar; see Benson's comment below.  Indeed, the thoughtful commentaries offer these remarks:

Pulpit -

> **The Everlasting Father**; rather, Everlasting or Eternal Father. But here, again, there is a singularity in the idea, which makes the
> omission of the article unimportant; for how could there be more than
> one Everlasting Father, one Creator, Preserver, Protector of mankind
> who was absolutely eternal? If the term "Father," applied to our Lord,
> grates on our ears, we must remember that the distinction of Persons
> in the Godhead had not yet been revealed.

Ellicott -

> In “Father of Eternity,” (LXX. Alex. and Vulg., “Father of the age to
> come “) we have a name which seems at first to clash with the
> formalised developments of Christian theology, which teach us, lest we
> should “confound the persons,” not to deal with the names of the
> Father and the Son as interchangeable. Those developments, however,
> were obviously not within Isaiah’s ken, and he uses the name of
> “Father” because none other expressed so well the true idea of loving
> and protecting government (Job 29:16, Isaiah 22:21). And if the
> kingdom was to be “for ever and ever,” then in some very real sense he
> would be, in that attribute of Fatherly government, a sharer in the
> eternity of Jehovah. Another rendering of the name, adopted by some
> critics, “Father (i.e., Giver) of booty,” has little to recommend it,
> and is entirely out of harmony with the majesty of the context.

Benson -

> The everlasting Father — Hebrew, אבי עד, The Father of eternity:
> having called him a child and a son, lest this should be
> misinterpreted to his disparagement, he adds that he is a Father also,
> even the Father of eternity, and, of course, of time, and of all
> creatures made in time. Christ, in union with the Father and the Holy
> Ghost, is the God and Father of all things, the maker and upholder of
> all creatures, John 1:3; Hebrews 1:3; and especially the Father of all
> believers, who are called his children, (Hebrews 2:13,) and the author
> of eternal life and salvation to them, Hebrews 5:9.

Answer (score 0):

Curiously the [text referenced](https://d2y1pz2y630308.cloudfront.net/15471/documents/2016/10/St.%20Athanasius-Select%20Works%20and%20Letters.pdf) in the OP, an English translation of Athanasius, references the LXX on page 266 when referring to Isaiah 9:6, which is **missing** any reference to the MT אבי עד. So either Athanasius had different version of the LXX than we have or he was in fact using another translation or the MT itself or the editor of this translation of Athanasius made a mistake.

The OT עד can appear in several forms with opposite meanings:

- עד *until* as in II Sam 7:18 עד הלם, *up to* as in Genesis 15:18
- ועד *and more* meaning "forever" as in לעולם ועד
- עוד *more than*, *still* in Genesis 45:3 העוד אבי חי

So while the simplest translation of the MT אבי עד in Isaiah 9:6 would be "eternal father", (the *yod* is a phonetic interjection like the *yod* in the names עדיאל, דניאל, and not first person possessive), there is definitely room for an interpretive translation of אבי עד as "father from then on" (future father), or "father to be" based on עד in the sense of *more than* or *future* with reference to time, especially if this translation fits the writer's agenda of being a reference to a future (with respect to the date of Isaiah) revelation of God.

I speculate that Athanasius's interpreted the name אבי עד in Isaiah 9:6 is as a reference to Genesis 49:10, עד כי יבא שילה.

Comment: If you can get the Göttingen LXX apparatus, it would be great what rendering it has. Coz Rahlf's LXX has this: His government shall be great, and of his peace there is no end: μεγάλη ἡ ἀρχὴ αὐτοῦ καὶ τῆς εἰρήνης αὐτοῦ οὐκ ἔστιν ὅριον There is no Father in the name. The Apostolic Bible has  πατήρ του μέλλοντος αιώνος Father of coming age.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus cannot be the Father of ETERNITY, because "Father" is the one who GENERATES and eternity was never generated.

See an example of a similar syntactic construction:

> וְלֹא־יִקָּרֵ֥א ע֛וֹד אֶת־שִׁמְךָ֖ אַבְרָ֑ם וְהָיָ֤ה שִׁמְךָ֙ אַבְרָהָ֔ם כִּ֛י **אַב־הֲמ֥וֹן** גּוֹיִ֖ם נְתַתִּֽיךָ׃  Genesis 17:5 HEBREW

**אַב־הֲמ֥וֹן** is equivalent to πατέρα πολλῶν ἐθνῶν "father of many nations"  Genesis 17:5 LXX

Now we observe the behavior of the same syntactical construction in the previous verse:

אֲנִ֕י הִנֵּ֥ה בְרִיתִ֖י אִתָּ֑ךְ וְהָיִ֕יתָ **לְאַ֖ב הֲמ֥וֹן גּוֹיִֽם**׃ Genesis 17:4 HEBREW

לְאַ֖ב הֲמ֥וֹן גּוֹיִֽם׃ is equivalent to πατὴρ πλήθους ἐθνῶν Genesis 17:4 LXX

In this syntactic structure, the noun גּוֹיִ֖ם (nation)  complements the noun הֲמ֥וֹן (abundance) in the construct.

Now let's review Isaiah 9:6:

כִּי־יֶ֣לֶד יֻלַּד־לָ֗נוּ בֵּ֚ן נִתַּן־לָ֔נוּ וַתְּהִ֥י הַמִּשְׂרָ֖ה עַל־שִׁכְמ֑וֹ וַיִּקְרָ֙א שְׁמ֜וֹ פֶּ֠לֶא יוֹעֵץ֙  אֵ֣ל גִּבּ֔וֹר **אֲבִיעַ֖ד** שַׂר־שָׁלֽוֹם׃   Isaiah 9:5 HEBREW

What happened here after **אֲבִיעַ֖ד** is the existence of ellipsis: a situation in which words are left out of a sentence but the sentence can still be understood, where the meaning of the word עַ֖ד (forever) is complemented by שָׁלֽוֹם (peace), this is also the same understanding of the Septuagint interpreter in translating the verse when he twice repeated the word **εἰρήνην** Isaiah 9:5 LXX

> ὅτι παιδίον ἐγεννήθη ἡμῖν υἱὸς καὶ ἐδόθη ἡμῖν οὗ ἡ ἀρχὴ ἐγενήθη ἐπὶ τοῦ ὤμου αὐτοῦ καὶ καλεῖται τὸ ὄνομα αὐτοῦ μεγάλης βουλῆς ἄγγελος ἐγὼ γὰρ ἄξω **εἰρήνην** ἐπὶ τοὺς ἄρχοντας **εἰρήνην** καὶ ὑγίειαν αὐτῷ Isaiah 9:5 LXX

The Targum Jonathan ben Uziel, Aramaic Translatio, Peshita, Syriac Translation, East Aramaic dialect. also followed the same understanding.

> The prophet said to the house of David, for us a child is born, for us a son is given, and He took the law upon Himself to keep it. His name is called from eternity of the Wonderful One, the Mighty God, who lives for eternity: The Messiah, whose peace will be great upon us in His days. Targum Jonathan ben Uziel, Aramaic Translation.

> Because a boy was born to us, a son was given to us and the dominion will be on his shoulders and his name will be: Wonderful Counselor, The Mighty One, The Eternal Ruler, Father of Peace, Messenger who was prepared in Eternity for the form of think bigger (Master). Peshita, Syriac Translation, East Aramaic dialect.

> Since a boy was born to us and a son was given to us, which at first became/came to be/was born upon His shoulder and is being called his name: Messenger of the Great Counselor. For I will lead you to peace, over rulers/commanders, you to peace and health to him. Septuagint, Greek Translation, Coine.

> Since a boy beside us is born, beside us a son is given, shall/come(?) to be and his command shall be upon His shoulder and called his name Wonderful, the Mighty of the Counselor Eternal God, Prince of Peace/Health. Hebrew, Westminster Leningrad Codex.

This is an example of the same syntactic construction:

הִנֵּ֤ה טְפָח֙וֹת׀ נָ֨תַ֤תָּה יָמַ֗י וְחֶלְדִּ֣י כְאַ֣יִן נֶגְדֶּ֑ךָ אַ֥ךְ **כָּֽל־הֶ֥בֶל כָּל־אָ֜דָ֗ם** נִצָּ֥ב סֶֽלָה׃  Ps. 39:6

The Septuagint renders:

πλὴν τὰ σύμπαντα ματαιότης πᾶς ἄνθρωπος ζῶν Salmos 38:6 LXX

moreover all *men* together *are* vanity, every man living.... Salmos 38:6 LXX

כָּֽל־הֶ֥בֶל  complete vanity

כָּל־אָ֜דָ֗ם  *is* every man

The logic is the same same for all similar constructions.

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer: I don’t speak for any sect.

> [Isa 9:6 NLT] (6) For a child is born to us, a son is given to us. The government will rest on his shoulders. And he will be called: Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace.

However, that is actually a mistranslation.

First of all, let me point out that traditional Christianity, aka Trinitarianism, likes to quote this verse, which is clearly Messianic, to say that the Messiah will be the Father (Almighty God). However, true Judaism and true Christianity are fiercely monotheistic. That is, while many are called “gods” in the scripture, there is always a sharp distinction between these heroes who are referred to as “gods” and such (as in the same name above) and God, the Father, the Almighty. This passage is not meant to blur that line.

The correct translation and significance is something more like “Father of Innumerable [Children]”:

[image: H5703 - `ad - Strong's Hebrew Lexicon (NLT)]

It is the word in the following verse for David’s innumerable troubles:

> [Psa 40:12 NLT] (12) For troubles surround me--too many to count! My sins pile up so high I can't see my way out. They outnumber the hairs on my head. I have lost all courage.

This becomes more obvious in the next verse:

> [Isa 9:7 NASB] (7) There will be no end to the increase of [His] government or of peace, On the throne of David and over his kingdom, To establish it and to uphold it with justice and righteousness From then on and forevermore. The zeal of the LORD of hosts will accomplish this.

This is how, of course, the promise to Abraham is brought to fruition:

> [Gen 15:5-6 NLT] (5) Then the LORD took Abram outside and said to him, "Look up into the sky and count the stars if you can. That's how many descendants you will have!" (6) And Abram believed the LORD, and the LORD counted him as righteous because of his faith.

See also:

> [Gen 24:60 NKJV] [60] And they blessed Rebekah and said to her: "Our sister, [may] you [become The mother of] thousands of ten thousands; And may your descendants possess The gates of those who hate them."

> [Num 10:36 NKJV] [36] And when it rested, he said: "Return, O LORD, [To] the many thousands of Israel."

> [Deu 33:2, 17 NKJV] [2] And he said: "The LORD came from Sinai, And dawned on them from Seir; He shone forth from Mount Paran, And He came with ten thousands of saints; From His right hand [Came] a fiery law for them. ... [17] His glory [is like] a firstborn bull, And his horns [like] the horns of the wild ox; Together with them He shall push the peoples To the ends of the earth; They [are] the ten thousands of Ephraim, And they [are] the thousands of Manasseh."

> [1Sa 18:8 NKJV] [8] Then Saul was very angry, and the saying displeased him; and he said, "They have ascribed to David ten thousands, and to me they have ascribed [only] thousands. Now [what] more can he have but the kingdom?"

> [Psa 68:17 NKJV] [17] The chariots of God [are] twenty thousand, [Even] thousands of thousands; The Lord is among them [as in] Sinai, in the Holy [Place].

> [Eph 3:21 NKJV] [21] to Him [be] glory in the church by Christ Jesus to all generations, forever and ever. Amen.

> [Rev 5:11 NKJV] [11] Then I looked, and I heard the voice of many angels around the throne, the living creatures, and the elders; and the number of them was ten thousand times ten thousand, and thousands of thousands,

We see the continuously increasing and uncountable number of descendants in Revelation:

> [Rev 7:9-12 NASB] (9) After these things I looked, and behold, a great multitude which no one could count, from every nation and [all] tribes and peoples and tongues, standing before the throne and before the Lamb, clothed in white robes, and palm branches [were] in their hands; (10) and they cry out with a loud voice, saying, "Salvation to our God who sits on the throne, and to the Lamb." (11) And all the angels were standing around the throne and [around] the elders and the four living creatures; and they fell on their faces before the throne and worshiped God, (12) saying, "Amen, blessing and glory and wisdom and thanksgiving and honor and power and might, [be] to our God forever and ever. Amen."

The 144,000 in the previous section are the chosen remnant of the lost sheep of the house of Israel, living and dead, reunited with faithful Jews from Judah into the “one stick” of the united kingdom of Israel, under the one shepherd, the Messiah/Christ per Ezekiel 37. These that come after are the ever growing Christians from all nations, including Israel, living and dead, and composed of both Jews and gentiles. They are the first fruits. They have a different origin story than those that follow but other than that, they are one covenant people along with the ever increasing number that comes after:

> [Eph 4:4-6 NLT] (4) For there is one body and one Spirit, just as you have been called to one glorious hope for the future. (5) There is one Lord, one faith, one baptism, (6) and one God and Father, who is over all and in all and living through all.

The ones in the first group were an elect remnant, chosen by God and their number is given. The ones that follow are innumerable because their numbers keep growing forever. They are as uncountable as the stars in the sky and as the sand of the sea. In fact, they are described, not as you see in English translations, those who “came out” but rather “are coming out of the great trouble”. It is a present continuous, ongoing reality.

The NASB has modified this by adding an inappropriate comma and adding the word “they” which obscures this so I’ve taken the liberty of putting both in brackets below:

> [Rev 7:13-17 NASB] (13) Then one of the elders answered, saying to me, "These who are clothed in the white robes, who are they, and where have they come from?" (14) I said to him, "My lord, you know." And he said to me, "These are the ones who come out of the great tribulation[,] and [they] have washed their robes and made them white in the blood of the Lamb. (15) "For this reason, they are before the throne of God; and they serve Him day and night in His temple; and He who sits on the throne will spread His tabernacle over them. (16) "They will hunger no longer, nor thirst anymore; nor will the sun beat down on them, nor any heat; (17) for the Lamb in the center of the throne will be their shepherd, and will guide them to springs of the water of life; and God will wipe every tear from their eyes."

The Jehovah’s Witnesses organization claims falsely to be the 144,000 and royalty which is patently false, and frankly, a despicable deception. They also claim that the 144,000 have a different hope. This is somewhat true only in that they were the ones who were to be raptured in order to join Jesus when he returned c. 70 AD/CE to judge the living and the dead of Israel:

> [Jude 1:14-15 NASB] (14) [It was] also about these men [that] Enoch, [in] the seventh [generation] from Adam, prophesied, saying, "Behold, the Lord came with many thousands of His holy ones, (15) to execute judgment upon all, and to convict all the ungodly of all their ungodly deeds which they have done in an ungodly way, and of all the harsh things which ungodly sinners have spoken against Him."

How might Jesus have returned with ten thousands of of his saints if he had not first caught them up into the air, to accompany Christ in his descent?

The “armies of heaven” are these elect 144,000:

> [Rev 19:14-15 NLT] (14) The armies of heaven, dressed in the finest of pure white linen, followed him on white horses. (15) From his mouth came a sharp sword to strike down the nations. He will rule them with an iron rod. He will release the fierce wrath of God, the Almighty, like juice flowing from a winepress.

> [Eze 37:10-14 NLT] (10) So I spoke the message as he commanded me, and breath came into their bodies. They all came to life and stood up on their feet--a great army. (11) Then he said to me, "Son of man, these bones represent the people of Israel. They are saying, 'We have become old, dry bones--all hope is gone. Our nation is finished.' (12) Therefore, prophesy to them and say, 'This is what the Sovereign LORD says: O my people, I will open your graves of exile and cause you to rise again. Then I will bring you back to the land of Israel. (13) When this happens, O my people, you will know that I am the LORD. (14) I will put my Spirit in you, and you will live again and return home to your own land. Then you will know that I, the LORD, have spoken, and I have done what I said. Yes, the LORD has spoken!'"

However, afterwards there is but one flock, one shepherd, one hope, which is the hope of everlasting life together with Christ.

Comment: The JW,s didnt teach Jesus returned in 70ad--Where do you get that? The remaining 144,000( little flock -Luke 12:32) on earth during the tribulation get changed in the twinkling of an eye and go to heaven to rule on thrones beside Jesus as kings and priests-Rev 1:6, Rev 20:6--The great crowd of other sheep are not promised heaven anywhere in the bible.

Comment: You as well fail to listen to Jesus who at Matt 23 told the Israelite religious teachers off and told them they are cut off of being Gods chosen at verse 38 unless they do verse 39--they have outright refused for over1950 years-they never will. Spiritual Israel is now Gods chosen.

Comment: "The JW,s didnt teach Jesus returned in 70ad--Where do you get that?" - I didn't say that. You misread my words.

Comment: So @kjw47, shall I presume that this is your preferred, practically angelic language translation?:

https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/nwt/books/isaiah/9/#v23009006

Do you believe Jesus to be the "Eternal Father"? Just because those posers said that's correct? Well, can you defend it from the greek as I did my reading? Or are you simply a bigot who thinks he need not defend his cult's views?

Comment: He is Father in the sense that he laid his life down for many to gain everlasting life, in that sense he is the eternal Father. Otherwise none had a chance. That ransom sacrifice gave many life like a Father does. But he is not his own Father. Nor the Father he said was THE ONLY TRUE GOD at John 17:3.

Comment: The Hebrew for "everlasting" (often rendered "eternal") is OLAM. That word is not used in Isaiah 9:6. It is AD. I provide the image in my answer, and highlight how he is using it. But, you prefer a crap translation just because it is from your cult. You're being partisan. That is not what his site is (ostensibly) about. I mean, it isn't supposed to be the way it is.

Comment: At Isaiah it doesn't say Jesus the man will be called those things. It says his name will be called those things. And if you are listening to trinity version, do not ever put your trust in their words. They twist many things. Like i am that i am does not exist in the Hebrew written OT, yet they translated it like that to mislead saying because Jesus said he lived before Abraham( i am) he was claiming to be God, but its not truth. He just answered honestly--he lived before Abraham.